# Colored Text under C language Osx [Xcode]

Tags: c, xcode, macos, textcolor

I want to know how to output a text on color in the C language.

I heard that some methods work on Windows but not on OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The standard "ANSI" escape sequences for colored text work just fine in Terminal windows on the Mac.  For example:

```
printf("\033[34mblue\033[0m\n");
```